# Pydap Client UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

Alright, so I am trying to extract some data from a specific catalog, although by the looks of it I am having some issues with opening the url through my pydap.client. The error seems to lie with the data being in utf-8, but I am unsure how to make sure the pydap.client recieves the decoded utf-8 codec.

```
from itertools import product
import threddsclient
import pydap.client
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import openpyxl as xl

years = list(range(2019,2020))
months = [1]
urls = []


for y, m in product(years, months):
    catalog = f'https://thredds.met.no/thredds/catalog/aromearcticarchive/{y:04d}/{m:02d}/catalog.html'
    if requests.get(catalog).status_code == 200:
        datasets = threddsclient.crawl(catalog, depth=1)
        urls += [ds.opendap_url() for ds in datasets if '_pp_' in ds.name]

ds = pydap.client.open_url(urls[0])
print(ds)
```

The error code lies in the `ds = pydap.client.open_url(urls[0])` part and looks as follows:
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte`

I am completely lost here, how would I ensure the correct decoding of my urls[0] item?

Comment: Maybe  `ds = pydap.client.open_url(urllib.parse.quote(urls[0]))` ?